# Test charge in 2+1 dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, chern-simons-theory, equations-of-motion

Given a Chern-Simons theory,as in [this resource](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Edavidgrabovsky/files-notes/CS%20and%20Knots.pdf)(page 4), in 2+1 dimensions we can define the electric and magnetic fields as
$$
E_i=-\partial_iA_0-\partial_0A_i\;\;\;B=\epsilon^{ij}\partial_iA_j
$$
since the electromagnetic field tensor is defined as
$$
F_{\mu\nu}=\left(\begin{matrix}0&E_1&E_2\\-E_1&0&-B\\-E_2&B&0\end{matrix}\right)
$$
If we then write the matter current as $J^\mu=(\rho,\vec{J})$ we have
$$
\rho=\frac{k}{2\pi}B=\frac{k}{2\pi}\epsilon^{ij}\partial_i A_j\;\;\;\;\;\;J^i=\frac{k}{2\pi}\epsilon^{ij}E_j=-\frac{k}{2\pi}\epsilon^{ij}(\partial_jA_0+\partial_0 A_j)
$$
I am trying to show that the equations of motion are solved by a moving charge as in
$$
\rho=\delta^{(2)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_\alpha(t))\;\;\;\vec{J}=\vec{0}
$$
**My attempt**

By substitution of the charge distribution we have
$$
\delta^{(2)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_a(t))=\frac{k}{2\pi}\epsilon^{ij}\partial_i A_j
$$
then using the Poisson equation $\nabla^2\log(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_a(t))=2\pi\delta^{(2)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_a(t))$ we have
$$
\nabla^2\log(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_a(t))=k\epsilon^{ij}\partial_i A_j
$$
From here I don't know how to compute the term on the left hand side and then integrate.

Comment: $\vec{J} = \dot{\vec{x}_\alpha} \delta\left(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_\alpha\right)$ cannot be zero! You can see this by taking the divergence of $\vec{J}$, which will give you $-\partial_0 \rho$, which is non-zero....

Comment: "I am trying to show that the equations of motion are solved by a moving charge as in " Do you mean you are trying to find a vector potential $A$ for a solution of the equations with given source density?